# In MySQL is it faster to execute one JOIN + one LIKE statement or two JOINs?

Tags: mysql, performance, join, sql-like

I have to create a cron job, which is simple in itself, but because it will run every minute I'm worried about performance. I have two tables, one has user names and the other has details about their network. Most of the time a user will belong to just one network, but it is theoretically possible that they might belong to more, but even then very few, maybe two or three. So, in order to reduce the number of JOINs, I saved the network ids separated by `|` in a field in the user table, e.g.

|1|3|9|

The (simplified for this question) user table structure is

```
TABLE `users` (
  `u_id` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE,
  `userid` VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  `net_ids` VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`u_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

The (also simplified) network table structure is

```
CREATE TABLE `network` (
  `n_id` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE,
  `netname` VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  `login_time` DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
  `timeout_mins` TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 10,
  PRIMARY KEY (`n_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I have to send a warning when timeout occurs, my query is

```
SELECT N.netname, N.timeout_mins, N.n_id, U.userid FROM
(SELECT netname, timeout_mins, n_id FROM network
 WHERE is_open = 1 AND notify = 1
 AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, TIMESTAMPADD(MINUTE, timeout_mins, login_time), NOW()) < 60) AS N
INNER JOIN users AS U ON U.net_ids LIKE CONCAT('%|', N.n_id, '|%');
```

I made N a subquery to reduce the number of rows joined. But I would like to know if it would be faster to add a third table with u_id and n_id as columns, removed the net_ids column from users and then do a join on all three tables? Because I read that using LIKE slows things down.

Which is the most effcient query to use in this case? One JOIN and a LIKE or two JOINS?

P.S. I did some experimentation and the initial values for using two JOINS are higher than using a JOIN and a LIKE. However, repeated runs of the same query seems to speed things up a lot, I suspect something is cached somewhere, either in my app or the database, and both become comparable, so I did not find this data satisfactory. It also contradicts what I was expecting based on what I have been reading.

I used this table:

```
TABLE `user_net` (
`u_id` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`n_id` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
INDEX `u_id` (`u_id`),
FOREIGN KEY (`u_id`) REFERENCES `users`(`u_id`),
INDEX `n_id` (`n_id`),
FOREIGN KEY (`n_id`) REFERENCES `network`(`n_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

and this query:

```
SELECT N.netname, N.timeout_mins, N.n_id, U.userid FROM
(SELECT netname, timeout_mins, n_id FROM network
 WHERE is_open = 1 AND notify = 1
 AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, TIMESTAMPADD(MINUTE, timeout_mins, login_time), NOW()) < 60) AS N
INNER JOIN user_net AS UN ON N.n_id = UN.n_id
INNER JOIN users AS U ON UN.u_id = U.u_id;
```

Comment: :-( Don't do that.

Comment: Check the execution plan. Don't guess. Although, `LIKE '%something%'` will always be slow - there's no way to use an index with such a string, which means that *every* row will be scanned

Comment: Don't use my current method? I realise it's not ideal design but my main concern is reducing the time for this query.

Comment: BTW, if you `net_ids` field contains a string with separated values, you have a serious (actually, terminal as in cancer) design bug - you are breaking 1NF by storing multiple values in a single cell. Use a separate table

Comment: How do I check the execution plan? I don't have access to phpMyAdmin. My client did not give me cPanel access. I have been using a simple form I made myself for running queries I must, like table creation.

Comment: @inarilo use your own database. Although, what you did with `net_ids` just can't be covered up. It's a very, very serious problem. If you created a many-to-many table that maps ids with the proper indexes, you could find the relevant rows just with a single lookup per row. Now, you have to read *every* single target row for *every* source row.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes I know, this kind of thing used to bother me a lot, but truth is often design is sacrificed for performance. The data is entered using a stored procedure and is generated internally so data inconsistency is not lilkely to occur.

Comment: Normalising the design will afford the use of indexes, so massively easing the execution time.

Comment: trying to optimize by 'reducing the number of joins' is the mistake.

Comment: @inarilo on the contrary, what you did eradicates performance. If you had 1000 rows, your query will end up to 1M times slower than a properly designed schema

Comment: I did try using a third table, like I said it had the opposite effect. Using the like statement was faster. Hence my confusion. I will try setting up my own database.

Comment: hmm, so I should just go with the multiple JOINs?

Comment: @inarilo only if you *didn't* use indexes. Instead of assuming that the database is broken and a standard design used for over 30 years is wrong, fix your bugs.

Comment: I did use indexes, primary keys as shown of course, and indexes+foreign key references in the third.

Comment: Make sure the many-to-many table contains *integer* columns, not text. If you try to join ints with text, you force a type conversion that prevents the use of any indexes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142509/discussion-between-inarilo-and-panagiotis-kanavos).

Comment: You *didn't* post the schema for a many-to-many table, so it's impossible to guess what went wrong

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i added the table structure and new query using it above. Please reply in the chat. I am getting repeated suggestions to move this to chat. I had sent you an invite.

Answer (score 1):

You should define [composite indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-column-indexes.html) for the `user_net` table. One of them can (and should) be the primary key.

```
TABLE `user_net` (
    `u_id` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `n_id` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`u_id`, `n_id`),
    INDEX `uid_nid` (`n_id`, `u_id`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`u_id`) REFERENCES `users`(`u_id`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`n_id`) REFERENCES `network`(`n_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I would also rewrite your query to:

```
SELECT N.netname, N.timeout_mins, N.n_id, U.userid
FROM network N
INNER JOIN user_net AS UN ON N.n_id = UN.n_id
INNER JOIN users AS U  ON UN.u_id   = U.u_id
WHERE N.is_open = 1 
  AND N.notify = 1
  AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, TIMESTAMPADD(MINUTE, N.timeout_mins, N.login_time), NOW()) < 60
```

While your subquery will probably not hurt much, there is no need for it.

Note that the last condition cannot use an index, because you have to combine two columns. If your MySQL version is at least 5.7.6 you can define an [indexed virtual (calculated) column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-secondary-indexes.html).

```
CREATE TABLE `network` (
  `n_id` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE,
  `netname` VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  `login_time` DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
  `timeout_mins` TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 10,
  `is_open` TINYINT UNSIGNED,
  `notify`  TINYINT UNSIGNED,
  `timeout_dt` DATETIME AS (`login_time` + INTERVAL `timeout_mins` MINUTE),
  PRIMARY KEY (`n_id`),
  INDEX (`timeout_dt`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Now change the query to:

```
SELECT N.netname, N.timeout_mins, N.n_id, U.userid
FROM network N
INNER JOIN user_net AS UN ON N.n_id = UN.n_id
INNER JOIN users AS U  ON UN.u_id   = U.u_id
WHERE N.is_open = 1 
  AND N.notify  = 1
  AND N.timeout_dt < NOW() + INTERVAL 60 SECOND
```

and it will be able to use the index.

You can also try to replace

```
INDEX (`timeout_dt`)
```

with

```
INDEX (`is_open`, `notify`, `timeout_dt`)
```

and see if it is of any help.

Comment: Thanks! I am using version 4.0something (I have no control over this). I'll try out the rest and get back.

Comment: Do I need to use a primary key and index if they are both same? I thought primary keys are automatically indexed.

Comment: @inarilo The order of columns in the index is important. `index(a, b)` is not the same as `index(b, a)`. For a many-to-many table you usually need both. BTW: You should have told us earlier, that you use an old version (10 years at least) - that might explain the issue with poor JOIN performance.

Comment: Oh I see. About the version, I did not realise it could affect JOIN performance. But I suppose it should still be relatively faster compared to a JOIN using LIKE.

Comment: I'm still getting inconsistent runtimes :( But your answer was definitely helpful so I am upvoting it. I'm probably going to go with a third option, not ideal, but much less unideal than my original solution.

Answer (score 0):

Reformulate to avoid hiding columns inside functions.  I can't grok your date expression, but note this:

```
login_time < NOW() - INTERVAL timeout_mins MINUTE
```

If you can achieve something like that, then this index should help:

```
INDEX(is_open, notify, login_time)
```

If that is not good enough, let's see the other formulation so we can compare them.

Having stuff separated by comma (or `|`) is likely to be a really bad idea.

Bottom line:  Assume that `JOINs` are not a performance problem, write the queries with as many `JOINs` as needed.  *Then* let's optimize *that*.

Comment: Interesting, I just tried this minutes before seeing this :) but everytime I try to define an index with three columns it accepts only the first two. I want to sort it so i'm using `ALTER TABLE network ADD INDEX notify_list (notify DESC, is_open DESC, login_time ASC);`, But even if I remove the sort order, it still accepts only two.columns, I actually wandered back to SE to find a solution to this. :/ Is this an issue with version 4?

Comment: Sorry, never mind, I was using describe to see the table definition and it was just indicating MUL for the first column, The index is fine.

Comment: @inarilo -  `ASC` and `DESC` are accepted, but ignored, in `INDEX` declarations.  So, (until 8.0) the Optimizer will not optimize an `ORDER BY` with a mixture of directions.  I'm flying blind - If you want more discussion, please show us the `CREATE TABLE` (not `DESCRIBE`) and `EXPLAIN`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help but I finally decided to do away with the joins and use a separate table with all necessary values. Child records are inserted for each network at the time the network is added, along with relevant user names. Notification times are updated with logins and logouts. I figured this makes more sense than repeatedly running the same join query. My cron job will just select records from this table which I am indexing on the notification time.